# How to make usercontrol take whole space of the region its injected into

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have a view which is injected into an region (Itemscontrol). The view only takes up space in the region depending on content size. I want that the view streches for whole height of the region. Here is code of my view:

```
    <UserControl x:Name="userControl" x:Class="DishPromo.Modules.Payments.SideCart.SideCartView"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:infUIFramework="clr-namespace:DishPromo.Infrastructure.UIFramework;assembly=DishPromo.Infrastructure"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
         xmlns:Convert="clr-namespace:DishPromo.Modules.Payments.SideCart"
         mc:Ignorable="d"  >
<UserControl.Resources>
    <Convert:ObjectToStringConverter x:Key="ToString" />
    <Convert:BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="ToVisibility" />
    <Convert:WOMsgVisibilityConverter x:Key="WOMsgVisibility" />
    <Convert:WorkOrderMsgConverter x:Key="WorkOrderMsg" />
    <Convert:RescheduleValueConverter x:Key="ValueConverter" />
    <Convert:PaymentAmountDueNow x:Key="PaymentAmountDueNow" />

    <Style TargetType="Button" x:Key="hotkeyStyle">
        <Setter Property="Width" Value="Auto"/>
        <Setter Property="Height" Value="25"/>
        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">

            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                    <Grid Background="Transparent">
                        <Border Name="border"                           
                        Padding="4,2" CornerRadius="3"
                        BorderBrush="DarkGray" 
                        />


                        <Rectangle x:Name="FVElement" Stretch="Fill" StrokeLineJoin="Miter" StrokeThickness="0.5" Opacity="0" RadiusX="2" RadiusY="2"
                               HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Fill="{StaticResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlLightLightBrushKey}}" Stroke="{StaticResource OEFlowButtonBorderStyle}"
                               >
                        </Rectangle>
                        <Rectangle x:Name="Background" StrokeLineJoin="Miter" StrokeThickness="0.5" Opacity="1" Margin="2" RadiusX="3" RadiusY="3">
                            <Rectangle.Fill>
                                <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="0,1" >
                                    <GradientStop Color="{StaticResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlColorKey}}" Offset="0.576" />
                                    <GradientStop Color="{StaticResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlLightLightColorKey}}" Offset="0" />
                                    <GradientStop Color="{StaticResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlColorKey}}" Offset="1" />
                                    <GradientStop Color="{StaticResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlLightColorKey}}" Offset="0.262" />
                                </LinearGradientBrush>
                            </Rectangle.Fill>
                            <Rectangle.Stroke>
                                <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,-1.85" StartPoint="0.5,1.5">
                                    <GradientStop Color="Black" Offset="0"/>
                                    <GradientStop Color="Black" Offset="1"/>
                                </LinearGradientBrush>
                            </Rectangle.Stroke>
                        </Rectangle>
                        <Path x:Name="WhiteBand" Height="4.25" Stretch="Fill" StrokeLineJoin="Miter" Fill="{StaticResource OEFlowButtonWhiteBandFillStyle}"
                          Data="M4.2160064,2.75 C4.2160064,1.6454305 5.1114369,1.7153466 6.2160064,1.7153466 L22.679308,1.7153466 C23.783877,1.7153466 24.679308,1.6454305 24.679308,2.75 24.679308,2.75 4.2160064,2.75 4.2160064,2.75 z" 
                          Margin="7,4,7,0" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>

                        <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Foreground="Black" FontWeight="Light"  
                               TextWrapping="WrapWithOverflow" Text="{TemplateBinding Content}" x:Name="btnName" >

                        </TextBlock>
                        <ContentPresenter />
                    </Grid>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                            <Setter TargetName="border" Property="BorderBrush" Value="#FF585151" />
                            <Setter Property="Cursor" Value="Hand" />
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="Background" >
                                <Setter.Value>
                                    <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="0,1" >
                                        <GradientStop Color="#FF219921" Offset="0.35"/>
                                        <GradientStop Color="#FF216B99" Offset="1"/>
                                    </LinearGradientBrush>
                                </Setter.Value>
                            </Setter>
                            <Setter  Property="RenderTransform" >
                                <Setter.Value>
                                    <TranslateTransform Y="0.5" />
                                </Setter.Value>
                            </Setter>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                            <Setter TargetName="border" Property="Opacity" Value="0.3" />
                            <Setter TargetName="Background" Property="Opacity"  Value="0.3" />
                            <Setter TargetName="FVElement" Property="Opacity" Value="0.3" />
                            <Setter TargetName="btnName" Property="Foreground" Value="Gray"/>
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</UserControl.Resources>
<DockPanel VerticalAlignment="Stretch" LastChildFill="True" >

    <DockPanel.InputBindings>
        <KeyBinding Command="{Binding MinPaymentOverride}" Gesture="SHIFT+CTRL+y"></KeyBinding>
        <KeyBinding Command="{Binding PIAMinPaymentOverride}" Gesture="SHIFT+CTRL+m"></KeyBinding>
        <KeyBinding Command="{Binding EFTOverride}" Gesture="SHIFT+CTRL+e"></KeyBinding>
        <KeyBinding Command="{Binding CCOverride}" Gesture="SHIFT+CTRL+c"></KeyBinding>
        <KeyBinding Command="{Binding OverrideCC}" Gesture="SHIFT+CTRL+c"></KeyBinding>
        <KeyBinding Command="{Binding OverrideSSN}"  Gesture="SHIFT+CTRL+s"></KeyBinding>
        <KeyBinding Command="{Binding OverrideCertificate}"  Gesture="SHIFT+CTRL+j"></KeyBinding>
        <KeyBinding Command="{Binding OverrideSellingAgent}"  Gesture="SHIFT+CTRL+d"></KeyBinding>
        <KeyBinding Command="{Binding OverrideRefCompany}"  Gesture="SHIFT+CTRL+i"></KeyBinding>
        <KeyBinding Command="{Binding OverrideSellingCompany}"  Gesture="SHIFT+CTRL+n"></KeyBinding>
    </DockPanel.InputBindings>

    <DockPanel.Style>
        <Style>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ChangeFocus}" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="FocusManager.FocusedElement" Value="{Binding ElementName=SidecartRemove}"/>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </DockPanel.Style>

    <!--<Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition />

    </Grid.RowDefinitions>-->
    <DockPanel x:Name="dpNotificationArea"  Margin="0"  VerticalAlignment="Bottom" AllowDrop="True" LastChildFill="True" >

        <!--<Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition MinHeight="350" />
            <RowDefinition Height="29"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="58"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="27"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>-->

        <Grid Grid.Row="3" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" DockPanel.Dock="Bottom">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="260"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

            <Label Grid.Column="0" Width="Auto" FontWeight="Bold" Foreground="Red">
                <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource PaymentAmountDueNow}">
                    <Binding Path="CustomerModel.AccountInfo.Pricer.PaymentRequired"/>
                    <Binding Path="CustomerModel.AccountInfo.AccountStatus"/>
                </MultiBinding>
            </Label>

            <StackPanel Grid.Column="1" x:Name="spPricerActionBar" Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Right">
                <Button Style="{StaticResource hotkeyStyle}" Width="80" x:Name="SidecartRemove" Command="{Binding RemoveCartItem}" 
                    IsEnabled="{Binding CustomerModel.ControlStatus.RemoveIsEnabled}" GotFocus="SidecartRemove_GotFocus">
                    <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Foreground="Black" FontWeight="Light"><Run Text="Re"/><Underline><Run Text="m"/></Underline><Run Text="ove"/></TextBlock>
                </Button>

                <Button x:Name="btnFeeWaived" Width="80" Content="Fees Waived" IsEnabled="{Binding IsFeeWaivedEnabled}" 
                    Command="{Binding ShowBattery}"  GotFocus="btnFeeWaived_GotFocus" />    
                <Button Width="100" Content="Price It" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Visibility="{Binding PriceItVisibility}"  Command="{Binding GetPricing}" Background="#FF6633" Style="{StaticResource PriceItStyle}"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </Grid>

        <StackPanel x:Name="spWorkOrder" Grid.Row="2" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" DockPanel.Dock="Bottom">
            <Grid Margin="0,0,0,6">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="75" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="50"/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <StackPanel Grid.Column="1" VerticalAlignment="Bottom">
                    <Button Width="70" Height="25" x:Name="btnReschedule1" Content="Reschedule" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Command="{Binding GetInstallDates}" CommandParameter="1"
                        Visibility="{Binding CustomerModel.AccountInfo.ScheduleInfo, ConverterParameter=1, Converter={StaticResource ToVisibility}}" />
                    <Button Width="70" x:Name="btnReschedule0" Content="Reschedule" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Command="{Binding GetInstallDates}" CommandParameter="0"
                        Visibility="{Binding CustomerModel.AccountInfo.ScheduleInfo, ConverterParameter=0, Converter={StaticResource ToVisibility}}" />
                </StackPanel>
                <StackPanel Grid.Column="0" VerticalAlignment="Bottom">
                    <Label Margin="0,5,0,5" Content="{Binding CustomerModel.AccountInfo.WorkorderInfo.DisconnectDate, Converter={StaticResource WorkOrderMsg}}"
                        HorizontalAlignment="Left" FontWeight="Bold" Foreground="Blue" Visibility="{Binding CustomerModel.AccountInfo.WorkorderInfo.DisconnectDate, ConverterParameter=0, Converter={StaticResource WOMsgVisibility}}" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                    <Label Margin="0,5,0,5" Content="{Binding CustomerModel.AccountInfo.ScheduleInfo[1], Converter={StaticResource ValueConverter}}" 
                        HorizontalAlignment="Left" FontWeight="Bold" Foreground="Blue" Visibility="{Binding Visibility, ElementName=btnReschedule1}" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                    <Label Margin="0,5,0,5" Content="{Binding CustomerModel.AccountInfo.ScheduleInfo[0], Converter={StaticResource ValueConverter}}" 
                        HorizontalAlignment="Left" FontWeight="Bold" Foreground="Blue" Visibility="{Binding Visibility, ElementName=btnReschedule0}" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </Grid>
        </StackPanel>

        <StackPanel x:Name="NetworkQualification" Grid.Row="1" Margin="4,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" DockPanel.Dock="Bottom">
            <TextBlock x:Name="txtbNetQualStatus" Text="{Binding CustomerModel.ServiceAddress.NetQualResult}"  Foreground="Blue" FontWeight="Bold" />
            <TextBlock x:Name="txtDupAddress" Text="{Binding CustomerModel.ServiceAddress.NoAddressFound}" Foreground="Blue" FontWeight="Bold"/>
        </StackPanel>

        <ListView  Grid.Row="0"  Name="lstSideCart" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" DockPanel.Dock="Top"
                   ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" ItemsSource="{Binding CustomerModel.AccountInfo.Services}" SelectionMode="Extended" 
                   SelectionChanged="lstSideCart_SelectionChanged" MaxHeight="781" VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch" >
        <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{Binding Path=ForegroundColor}"/>
                <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="{Binding Path=FontWeight}"/>
                <Setter Property="BorderBrush">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="0,1" >
                            <GradientStop Color="DarkGray" Offset="0.0" />
                            <GradientStop Color="DarkGray" Offset="1.0" />
                        </LinearGradientBrush>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
                <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0,0,0,0.5"/>
            </Style>
        </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <ListView.ContextMenu>
            <ContextMenu ItemsSource="{Binding ContextMenuList}">
                <ContextMenu.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <MenuItem Header="{Binding Path=Header}" CommandParameter="{Binding}"
                                  Click="MenuItem_Click" Visibility="{Binding Path=IsVisible}" Height="16"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ContextMenu.ItemTemplate>
            </ContextMenu>
        </ListView.ContextMenu>
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView>
                <GridViewColumn Width="175" Header="Service Code Name" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Description}" />
                <GridViewColumn Width="100" Header="Service Type" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding ServiceCode.SecondaryServiceTypeSingle.ServiceTypeName}"/>
                <GridViewColumn Width="25" Header="#" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding CurrentQuantity}"/>
                <GridViewColumn Width="68" Header="Added" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=DateAdded, StringFormat={}{0:MM/dd/yy}}"/>
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
    </ListView>

    </DockPanel>

</DockPanel>
```

Answer (score 1):

What's the `ItemsPanelTemplate` of your `ItemsControl`?

The default is a `StackPanel`, which won't automatically stretch its child elements to the maximum allowed size.

You'll either have to set `HorizontalAlignment` to `Stretch` in the `ItemsContainerStyle`, or change the `ItemsPanelTemplate` to something that automatically stretches its children.

```
<!-- ItemContainerStyle -->
<ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
    <Style>
        <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
    </Style>
</ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
```

Comment: @NavneetDuggal What is your `ItemsControl` wrapped in? You may have to set the HorizontalAlignment of that, and of your `StackPanel` in the `ItemsPanelTemplate` as well. I'd suggest using a tool like [Snoop](http://snoopwpf.codeplex.com/) to find out what control is not stretching correctly.

Answer (score 1):

How about using a `UniformGrid` for your `ItemsPanelTemplate` like so

```
<ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
      <UniformGrid  />
    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
</ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
```

Also, StackPanels by their definition only take up space according to the content which exists, so saying something like `VerticalAlignment="Stretch"` won't stretch the contents of the StackPanel throughout the parent container.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use a Grid as the layoutroot of your usercontrol and dont set the width and height.